# Estimation of unobserved Hawkes Process

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, stochastic-processes, hawkes-process

I have been trying to implement following procedure:
1. Generate Hawkes process with parameters following SDE 
$$d\lambda_t = \kappa (\lambda_\infty - \lambda_t)dt + \delta_1 dN_t $$

2.Estimate parameters of the realised arrival times using MLE
$$ ln(\mathcal{L}((N_t)_{t\in[0,T]}) = \int _0^T (1-\lambda(s))ds + \int _0^Tln\lambda(s) dN_t $$

MLE estimation works reasonably well for long interval with large number of realised arrival times $\tau_i$. However what I am truly interested are very short intervals on which most of the time no jump occurs.

So essentially what I am interested in is:

Imagine I have a large number of hawkes process sample paths coming from the same family with the same parameters. Given that the interval is short most of the time I do not observe any jump, however I observe that the process to place. Now my question is how to take this in to account for parameters estimation? Any clues or links to relevant resources welcome!

Comment: I‘m not sure what you are asking. A sample path without jumps gives a contribution equal to the first term.

Comment: Do you observe $\lambda$, or its initial value?